# Multiplying 2 arrays with different number of rows and columns in Excel

Tags: excel

I have 2 Excel tables.

Table 1 has 200 rows x 50 columns.
Table 2 has 200 rows by 1 column

How can I use the MMULT function (or another function) to produce a table that has:

- Each column in Table 1's row 1 multiplied by the value in Table 2's row 1
- Each column in Table 1's row 2 multiplied by the value in Table 2's row 2
- ...etc.

Finally this table should be TRANSPOSED.  So the final output table should be 50x200 rows/columns.

Answer (score 1):

Highlight a 50x200 range such as BB1:IS50 (You can also just type this range into the namebox located to the left of the formula bar and press enter.

Then use:

```
=TRANSPOSE(A1:AX200*AZ1:AZ200)
```

You will need to press CTRL + SHIFT+ ENTER.